# Location Count issue in Java program

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee

I a working on GPS location where i need to convert latitude and longitude in corresponding address. I have a database of all latitude and longitude(more than 1,50,000 data) with its actual landmark i.e. address in one master table.

We have installed GPS device on many vehicles which is moving across all geographic location. Every 2 minute this device sends the actual position in term of latitude and longitude, i get this latitude and longitude and maps to our Master table and check near by which landmark from our master table. For doing this calculation i do some mathematical operation to add some delta value to latitude and longitude get from vehicle and then find the nearest search from my master table, once we find we show vehicle is 5 KM from XYZ location, we get XYZ location from master table which is nearest point.

This program basically takes lot of time to calculate the location, since we have 10,000 GPS devices installed on Vehicle and every device send GPS data in 2 minute, so you may imagine how much data we do get.

Could you please help me to fix this issue and make it very scalable and fast.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: break it down into the component parts and see what is taking the longest time, focus your efforts there. Is it the send of the data back? is it the calculation? is it the SQL search for the location? what's taking the time?  you need to break it down into A-->B-->C-->D-->E-->F etc. and figure out how long each step takes and focus your time on where you get the biggest bang for the buck. keep doing that until performance is acceptable. If you don't have a means of tracking the time from A-->F then you need to build it.

Comment: @xQbert We have a table where we have three column latitude, longitude and location - once i get any latitude and longitude from device we insert in latitude and longitude column , but we dont insert anything in Location column, after doing calculation with master table by sending latitude and longitude we get Location like 5 KM from XYZ then we update in location column of first table. Actually passing latitude and longitude to master table to get nearest location from our available landmark in master table takes much time, I am asking help to improve here. thanks

Comment: So you have a procedure? function? or something which is long running in SQL Server 200X? or MySQL, or ORACLE or DB2 or... If so, it would help to see things like the actual long running SQL and the Execution plan to assist in improving performance. or are you making repeated attempts from Java to the database to try and find the "closest" landmark?

Comment: @xQbert Yes i do repeated attempt to find nearest location and i am using SQL server 2005 and i am using function not procedure.

Comment: Can  switching from SQL to MongoDB will help?

Comment: Instead of doing repeated attempts from Java to the database do one trip and so and let the database return the nearest.  This may entail using some T-SQL instead of just SQL and a procedure.  Depending on the formula's you're using to get to the "nearest" the repeated calls and close and open of connections and return trips and evaluations are liekly a large bottleneck. if you had the database do the heavy lifting of identifying the nearest and returning what you needed from it, you'd likely be better off.  Keep in mind this site is about CODE.. we need CODE to help.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a GIS layer on your db? Something like PostGIS adds a new layer to sql with just that kind of functinality. From an [FAQ](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.3/ch03.html#id2570802):

> 3.7.   What is the best way to find all objects within a radius of another object?
>
> To use the database most efficiently, it is best to do radius queries
>   which combine the radius test with a bounding box test: the bounding
>   box test uses the spatial index, giving fast access to a subset of
>   data which the radius test is then applied to.
>
> The ST_DWithin(geometry, geometry, distance) function is a handy way
>   of performing an indexed distance search. It works by creating a
>   search rectangle large enough to enclose the distance radius, then
>   performing an exact distance search on the indexed subset of results.
>
> For example, to find all objects with 100 meters of POINT(1000 1000)
>   the following query would work well:
>
> SELECT * FROM geotable    WHERE ST_DWithin(geocolumn, 'POINT(1000
>   1000)', 100.0);